# Boolean Method for ArrayList

Tags: methods, arraylist, boolean

I have created an `ArrayList` and I am looking to use a `boolean` method to add an element to the `ArrayList`.

```
private static Arraylist <Bicycle> bikelist = new Arraylist<Bicycle>();

public boolean add(Bicycle bicycle)
{
    if( bikelist.size() != -1)
        return true;
    bikelist.add(bicycle);
}

return false;
```

Would this be plausible? I'm not quite sure how boolean methods work? Do they have to contain an `if` statement to return `true` or `false`?

Comment: After formatting your code it looks really strange. Have you noticed that `return false;` is outside of the method? Why you compare list size with `-1`? It's never `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Using: public boolean add(Object obj): Adds an element obj to the Arraylist. If the element is added successfully, this method returns true

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to return the boolean value for.

For whether the `add` operation succeeded: the only reason why adding an `Object` to an `ArrayList` would fail is due to an `OutOfMemoryException` AFAIK. Then you would do:

```
public boolean add(Object obj) {
    try {
        list.add(obj);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryException e) {
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
 }
```

If you want to return `false` if the list already contains the object, then:

```
public boolean add(Object obj) {
    if (list.contains(obj)) {
        return false;
    }
    list.add(obj);
    return true;
 }
```

Note that `ArrayList<T>.contains(T)` checks for object equality using `Object.equals(Object)`. Thus you need to override `equals()` for your custom class.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Bicycle other = (Bicycle) obj;
    if (other.owner != this.owner) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.model != other.model) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```